# Weight the probability of a prediction based on historical accuracy

Tags: probability, average

I have six predictions from six different sources. Each prediction has a percent probability that the prediction will happen, as well as a historical accuracy percentage.

Here's a table of my problem:

[image]

This is the link to the table:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fioSBZiucRwsyeUD4foi2Bt2tBAUXSpv9Esvgksm_mk/edit?usp=sharing

An example of how to read this would be TF predicts the likelihood of a 0 is 63% and has been historically correct 43% of the time.

I want to find if the prediction should be 1 or 0 by weighting predictions with more historical accuracy. For example, TF predicts 0 with a probability of 63%. It has a historical accuracy of 43%. In contrast, LINE predicts 1 with a 81% probability and the same 73% historical accuracy. I want the overall prediction between these two sources to be 1 because LINE has a higher probability than TF and a higher historical accuracy.

So, my question is: how can I mathematically find the average prediction weighted by probability and historical accuracy?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean
Above is reference.  The basic formula is $p=\frac{\sum p_ia_i}{\sum a_i}$.  Where $p$ is the probability you want and $p_i,a_i$ are the individual probabilities and accuracy.